# Cannot upload multiple file with CodeIgniter 3

Tags: codeigniter

With my code below it can be uploaded just the single file but cannot upload multiple file please advise me what i am doing wrong.

Here is the error message.

> Array ( [error] =>
>   You did not select a file to upload.

)

**UPDATE MY QUESTION**
when I do

```
echo $i.":".$_FILES['file_upload']['name'][$i].'<br/>';
```

Here is the result

> 0:heading-title-bg.jpg 
>   1:varun.jpg

But after I changed the code to

```
$_FILES['file_upload']['name'] = $_FILES['file_upload']['name'][$i];
echo $i.":".$_FILES['file_upload']['name'].'<br/>';
```

Here is result :

> 0:heading-title-bg.jpg
>   1:e

**//CONTROLLER**

```
public function addPhoto(){

            if (!empty($_FILES)):
                $count = count($_FILES['file_upload']['name']); 
                for($i =0; $i<$count;$i++):

                    $_FILES['file_upload']['name']      = $_FILES['file_upload']['name'][$i];
                    $_FILES['file_upload']['type']      = $_FILES['file_upload']['type'][$i];
                    $_FILES['file_upload']['tmp_name']  = $_FILES['file_upload']['tmp_name'][$i];
                    $_FILES['file_upload']['error']     = $_FILES['file_upload']['error'][$i];
                    $_FILES['file_upload']['size']      = $_FILES['file_upload']['size'][$i];

                    $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/employee/';
                    $config['allowed_types']        = 'jpg|png';
                    $config['max_size']             = 5000;
                    $config['max_width']            = 0;
                    $config['max_height']           = 0;
                    $config['overwrite']            = FALSE;
                    $config['remove_spaces']        = TRUE;

                    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                    $this->upload->initialize($config);


                    if($this->upload->do_upload('file_upload')){

                        $data = $this->upload->data();
                        echo "<pre>";
                        print_r($data);
                        echo "</pre>";

                    }else{
                        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                        print_r($error);
                    } 

                endfor;

            endif; //$_FILE

    }
```

**VIEW**

```
<input type="file" name="file_upload[]" class="form-control-file" id="fileUpload" multiple>
```

Comment: Why do you also count the  `['name']` field

Comment: what do u get if you do: `var_dump($_FILES['file_upload']);die();` right at the top of the function?

Comment: array(5) {
  ["name"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(38) "Screen Shot 2560-08-28 at 13.40.35.png"
    [1]=>
    string(38) "Screen Shot 2560-08-28 at 19.47.01.png"
  }
  ["type"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(9) "image/png"
    [1]=>
    string(9) "image/png"
  }
  ["tmp_name"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(14) "/tmp/phpJnbSu4"
    [1]=>
    string(14) "/tmp/phpUMFg8l"
  }
  ["error"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    int(0)
    [1]=>
    int(0)
  }
  ["size"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    int(110397)
    [1]=>
    int(83195)
  }
}

Comment: Here is the result when I use var_dump($_FILES['file_upload']);die()

Comment: did you see my update question I think maybe have the problem in loop-for. 
after I test echo $_FILES['file_upload']['name'] = $_FILES['file_upload']['name'][$i]  here is the result 
0:heading-title-bg.jpg 
1:e

the name of file number two has changed there is only have the secondary character of file name.

Answer (score 0):

This is working code in my project

```
    $data = array();
            $filesCount = count($_FILES['daily_records']['name']);
            for($i = 0; $i < $filesCount; $i++){
            $_FILES['daily_record']['name'] = $time."-".$_FILES['daily_records']['name'][$i];
            $_FILES['daily_record']['type'] = $_FILES['daily_records']['type'][$i];
            $_FILES['daily_record']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['daily_records']['tmp_name'][$i];
            $_FILES['daily_record']['error'] = $_FILES['daily_records']['error'][$i];
            $_FILES['daily_record']['size'] = $_FILES['daily_records']['size'][$i];
            $uploadPath = './assets/uploads/daily_records/daily_record';
            $config['upload_path'] = $uploadPath;
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|pdf|docx';
            //$config['max_size']   = '100';
            //$config['max_width'] = '1024';
            //$config['max_height'] = '768';

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            $this->upload->initialize($config);
            if($this->upload->do_upload('daily_record')){
            $fileData = $this->upload->data();
            $file_name = $fileData['file_name'];
            echo $file_name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have already fixed by myself.

**Here is my final code now is work for me.**

```
              foreach ($_FILES as $key => $v) {

                    for (   $i = 0; $i < count($v['name']); $i++ ){
                        $_FILES['file_upload']['name']      = $v['name'][$i];
                        $_FILES['file_upload']['type']      = $v['type'][$i];
                        $_FILES['file_upload']['tmp_name']  = $v['tmp_name'][$i];
                        $_FILES['file_upload']['error']     = $v['error'][$i];
                        $_FILES['file_upload']['size']      = $v['size'][$i];

                        //echo $_FILES['file_upload']['name'] ; 

                        if(! $this->upload->do_upload('file_upload')){
                            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                            print_r($error);

                        }else{
                            $data = $this->upload->data();
                            echo "<pre>";
                            print_r($data);
                            echo "</pre>";
                        } 
                    }                       
                }
```